# how to write formatted text into a file

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, streamwriter

I was trying to write to a file from textbox input with date:

Here is a part of the code:

```
DateTime dt=System::DateTime::Now;
System::IO::StreamWriter^ history = gcnew StreamWriter("history.txt");
history->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
history->WriteLine(dt);
history->Close();
```

But the output is like this: `text 
                       09/02/2015 23:26:07`

But I want it to be like: 
`text 09/02/2015 23:26:07`

And also has to append next input to next line of the file. 
It's something like a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    history->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
```

Using WriteLine() causes the line break of course.  You'd have to use Write() instead.  And fret a bit about how you get the extra space between the text and the date, never hesitate to use composite formatting in .NET:

```
    history->WriteLine("{0} {1}", textBox1->Text, System::DateTime::Now);
```

Answer (score 2):

you use two writeLine and so that write it in 2 Line concat them to write it in one line

`history->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
history->WriteLine(dt);`

change this part to
`history->write(textBox1->Text);
history->writeLine(dt);`

Comment: Sorry, it does not have a "\n"... i just put that to show a next line because it is not properly formatted when question was posted. i don't know how to post i guess...

Comment: oops you use write line twice that why you write wrong in text

Comment: 2 answers are both right. but how can i append, i mean write to the same file without overwriting the previous line.

Comment: you must seek in file. seek is a method